# Number of digits for an int to use in a file name in c++

Tags: c++, string, int, fstream, digit

I need to use some integer values as a part of some file names I create as outputs in a c++ program. For this I use the code above. The thing is my int values ( named n_irrad in the code) goes from 1 to 20000 for example, so I need the file names to be MC_Interface00001.txt, MC_Interface00002.txt, ..., MC_Interface20000.txt. So, ¿how can I set the number of digits in the file name? With the code I'm using I obviously get MC_Interface1.txt, MC_Interface2.txt, ..., MC_Interface20000.txt.

Thanks in advance.

```
ofstream MC_Interface;
string Irrad = static_cast<ostringstream*>( &(ostringstream() << n_irrad) )->str();
string MC_Interface_FileName = "MC_Interface" + Irrad + ".txt";
MC_Interface.open(MC_Interface_FileName.c_str());
```

Comment: Use [setw](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setw/) and [setfill](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setfill/).

Comment: Why the casting for the `std::ostringstream` formatting? Doing e.g. `std::string Irrad = (std::ostringstream() << n_irrad).str();` should work just as fine.

Comment: @user2079303 Why don't you add it as an answer?

Comment: @Joachim That won’t work, `operator<<` returns an `ostream` which has no `str` member function. I’m not sure why this is a pointer cast though – it should be a reference cast instead.

Comment: @KonradRudolph In that case clang's libc++ contain a bug, because it works fine there.

Comment: @Joachim That fails for me too.

Comment: @Konrad If I don't use a pointer it also fails for me. Not sure why really.

Comment: @Pablo I mean `static_cast<ostringstream const&>(ostringstream() << y).str()` – that definitely works.

Comment: @Konrad  It works, sorry. My fault, I was keeping ->str(). Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>

int main() 
{
    std::ostringstream os;

    os << std::setw( 5 ) << std::setfill( '0' ) << 10;

    std::string s = "MC_Interface" + os.str();
    std::cout << s << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
MC_Interface00010
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ofstream MC_Interface;
std::stringstream ss("MC_Interface");
ss << std::setw(5) << std::setfill('0') << n_irrad;
ss << ".txt";
MC_Interface.open(ss.str());
```

Comment: I missclicked I was editing sorry.